# java script function inside razor block

Tags: javascript, razor

I am calling a EditDetails javascript function on click only if user has Admin permissions else disabling the button.

I see the error 
"Cannot implicitly convert type bool to string " at the javascript function name.

What may be the issue?

```
 <img src='../../Images/Edit.png' alt='Click to Edit' 
 onclick="@(Model.AdminPermissions ? "javascript:EditDetails('#@rowId');" ? "")" disabled="@(Model.AdminPermissions ? "" : "disabled")"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error you were seeing is because you had accidentally included an extra `?` inside of your `@()` block, and it should have been a `:`

[image]

Overall, it was close you just need to make sure that you break out of the string concatenation and get back to the razor (server) scope for the `rowId`.

```
<img src='../../Images/Edit.png' alt='Click to Edit' 
    onclick="@(
        Model.AdminPermissions ? "javascript:EditDetails('#" + rowId + "');" 
                               : ""
    )"
    disabled="@(Model.AdminPermissions ? "" : "disabled")
/>
```